# Internationalization in .NET. Database driven? Resources interactively?

Tags: vb.net, database-design, resources, internationalization

I am working on the internationalization of a CMS in .NET (VB.NET). In the administration part we used resources, but for the clients we want a UI so someone can see the labels and translate them from one language to another.

So, the first thought was to do it database driven with three tables:

```
Label     Translation          Language
-----     -----------          --------
id         id                  id
name       keyname_id          name
filename   language_id
           value
```

And then create an UI so you can allow the client to first select the filename of the page you want to translate, the label, and then select the language he wants and translate it, and it would be stored in the translations table.
I see here a problem: How would I take from the page all the labels?

I also spotted an example of a resources manager that can translate in an interactive way. [This is the example](http://www.west-wind.com/tools/wwDbResourceProvider/docs/).
The benefits of this solution is that you are working with resources, so everything seems easier because some work is done. On the other hand, this structure can be more difficult to implement, I don't know as I'm not experienced on this.

So, what do you think about these two approaches? What is better for you? Maybe there is a third approach that is easier?

---

**EDIT:** I also found this link about [Resource-provider model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx). What do you think about it? Maybe it can be useful,but I don't know, maybe it's too much for my purposes. I am thinking where to start

Comment: See these questions [How to translate ASP.Net website in another language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973632/how-to-translate-website-in-another-languageasp-net-c) and [Effective strategies for localisation in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253614/effective-strategies-for-localization-in-net)

Comment: OK. I'll check them . Thank you!

Comment: hmm... I read them and they are quite useful, the first one are nice recommendations,ok, and the second one gives good ideas for translation, but there is no UI, in fact I translated a part of the CMS with this techniques, but there is a part for the client, and there I need an UI so he can choose his labels and translate them easily. Thanks for these links! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In LedgerSMB, we went with the following approach:

1. Application strings (and strings in code) get translated by a standard i18n framework (GNU gettext basically).
2. Business data gets manual translation in the database.  So you can add translations to department names, project names,descriptions of goods and services etc.

Our approach to the problem you say is to join the other tables, so we might have:

```
CREATE TABLE parts (
   id int primary key.... -- autoincrements but not relevant to this example
   description text,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE language (
   code varchar(5) primary key, -- like en_US
   name text unique,
);

CREATE TABLE parts_translation (
   parts_id int not null references parts(id),
   language_code varchar(5) not null references language(code),
   translation text
);
```

Then we can query based on desired language at run time.